# Grab data from json

Tags: php, arrays

Need to grab data from different levels in an array. I am interested in the ID, status, company identifier (xyz company) and actual hours.

- This is just one item for example but it will have to loop a much bigger JSON.

```
<?php
$result = json_decode($response, true);
foreach($result as $key=>$val){
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>$val[id]</td>";
echo "<td>$val[status]</td>";
echo "<td>$val[company]</td>";
echo "<td>$val[actualHours]</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
?>

This is the json I am pulling

[  
   {  
      "id":104805,
      "summary":"this is a summary",
      "board":{  
         "id":1,
         "name":"Help Desk",
         "_info":{  
            "board_href":"https://blalblalba.com"
         }
      },
      "status":{  
         "id":1,
         "name":"In Progress"
      },
      "company":{  
         "id":19696,
         "identifier":"xyz company",
         "name":"xyz company"
      },
      "actualHours":5,
      "approved":true
   }
]
```

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: Sorry I have included that now.

Comment: Look up "traverse array recursive php" and it should point your to a solution.

Comment: Did the answer help?  If not, I’ll take it down because I detest drive-by down voters.

Comment: No reply; working example deleted.